# Rails code completion with Netbeans 7.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans

Rails code completion does not work with Netbeans 7.3,But of Ruby works

Anyone have solution for Rails?

Comment: did you install this http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38549/ruby-and-rails plugins?

Comment: recomended plese use rubymine for full support on ruby on rails and it is the best ide

Comment: yes,all plugins are installed! code completion is the only problem.